# Nhibernate foreign key to foreign key collection mapping?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Staff and e SecuredPage entity and the properties are below

### Staff

id
Name
LastName
Level // SecuredPage.RoleId

### SecuredPage

id
PageId
RoleId // Staff.Level

I want to have a collection of SecuredPage in Staff entity, so it s a one-to-many but i couldnt figure it out how to handle with it in mapping.

Staff.hbm.xml

```
<bag name="SecuredPages"  lazy="true" inverse="false" cascade="none">
      <key column="RoleId" />
      <many-to-many class="RealEstate.Core.Domain.SecuredPage,RealEstate.Core" />
</bag>
```

with the code above Nhibernate gets all the records from SecuredPage table where

```
SecuredPage.RoleId = Staff.id
```

But i want it to be

```
SecurePage.RoleId = Staff.StaffLevel
```

I didnt create a Role Entity for some reasons that's why i am directly trying to get secured pages for Staff based on its Level(Role)

I hope i could tell you about my problem. I have checked Nhibernate guide, read all about collections mappings but i couldnt figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that it's not *really* a one to many.  In reality, that is an expression of a many-to-many relationship.

I know this doesn't sound like what you wanted to hear (as you said you didn't create a Role entity) but you may want to consider doing so for your own sake.

Is there a "Role" table that would act as the cross-reference between these two tables you presented?

If not, you should make one and that will help to resolve the problem.  If so, you may want to consider the relationship between employees and roles as being direct, and employees and SecuredPages as being indirect (through roles, which it is).

EDIT: Can you tell us why you didn't create a "Role" entity?  That may help to clarify for us.